# What happened to magit-remote-update in version 2.1

Tags: magit

The previous version of Magit had a remote update command to replicate

> git remote update

What is the replacement command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is now called `magit-fetch-all`, and can be invoked by `f a`.

Comment: git v1.6.5 learned `fetch --all` which does the same thing as `remote udpate`.  It is a straightforward naming to *fetch* changes from *all* repos.  I've also changed my habit to type `git fetch --all --prune` at a command prompt.